# How can I use Restsharp by Generic object parsing?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, restsharp

My question is related to RestSharp usage. I saw lots of documentation but I guess there lots of version differences because of that it created knowledge pollution. Anyway, I Have a request and a response. If you look at content of request and response below sample, you will be see Employee it can be changable, Employee has 3 properties, Tomorrow it will be Customer that has 5 properties. How can I create or handle in restsharp?

MyCode:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string body = Resource1.body;
            var client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/instances/RBFFiyatlama2_1.0.1");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("kieserver", "@test2018");

            var request = new RestRequest();

            request.Method = Method.POST;
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.Parameters.Clear();
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddBody(new { salary = 1000, cofactor = 1.2, age = 35 });
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {

        public double cofactor { get; set; }
        public double salary { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }


    }
}
```

[image]

Request:

```
{
  "commands": [ 
    {
      "insert": {
        "object": {
       "Employee": {
          "age": 35,  "cofactor" :0.2 , "salary":  2000
      }
        },
        "out-identifier": "t1",
        "return-object": true
      }
    }, 
    {
      "fire-all-rules": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
   "type": "SUCCESS",
   "msg": "Container RBFFiyatlama2_1.0.1 successfully called.",
   "result": {"execution-results":    {
      "results":       [
                  {
            "value": 1,
            "key": ""
         },
                  {
            "value": {"com.myteam.rbffiyatlama2.Employee":             {
               "salary": 2400,
               "age": 35,
               "cofactor": 0.2
            }},
            "key": "t1"
         }
      ],
      "facts": [      {
         "value": {"org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle": {"external-form": "0:37:1872522807:1872522807:73:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.myteam.rbffiyatlama2.Employee"}},
         "key": "t1"
      }]
   }}
}
```

Comment: So create a class `RequestWrapper<TRequest>` and `ResponseWrapper<TResponse>`, and use those with `Employee` as generic argument?

Comment: It's preferable if you post the json as text instead of screen shots.

Comment: @juharr I updated my question.